# Restore a lost partition from degraded software mirror RAID

Tags: disk-utility, partition, raid, mirroring

I used to store my valuable files on Apple software RAID (mirror). Recently one disk has failed and the mirror became degraded.

I rebuilt the mirror using new drive, following [this](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/99121010260/recovering-from-a-failed-drive-with-apples-software) guide, but seems like there are no partitions on it.

I believe the data on the healthy drive is not corrupted. What programs should I use at this point to retrieve if not the lost partition, but data?

Comment: What's your system? Did you document your steps trying to rebuild your RAID? If not, you may check your ~/.bash_history file(s) and post all commands you executed here. Please add additionally the output of `diskutil list` and `diskutil appleraid list` to your question.

Comment: @klanomath I followed [this](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/99121010260/recovering-from-a-failed-drive-with-apples-software) guide and the mirror has successfully rebuilt. However partition was not magically reappeared, so I tried to salvage at least my Lightroom catalog with the aid of programs listed in my answer. I've recovered some files, but they are all heavily outdated, so I gave up on restoration. I learned not to use Apple RAID in the future due to its scarcely documented nature and unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following programs to retrieve your data from lost/damaged partitions: FileSalvage, Data Rescue, Stellar Phoenix Mac Data Recovery, DiskWarrior. The good practice is to create an image of the actual partition and restore data from it.

Comment: Can you add some more details? Also I don't assume that you used all of the applications listed, so describing how you used one of them to recover your data might be of interest for a broader audience.